# AT+IPSCAN HC-05 Command

Tags: arduino-uno, hc-05, stm32

I have a HC-05 module, directly connected to an STM32 via UART interface and connected simultaneously to a mobile application in order to exchange
real time data. I am trying to reduce the power consumption of my HC-05 BT module. After few researches, I discovered that if I set the command AT+IPSCAN and
put the Query duration (2nd parameter) and the Call duration (4th parameter) to 1, the current dramatically decreases. Thus, the energy which the BT
module consumes decreases as well. My problem is I didn't understand how and why it decreases ? What are exatly the parameters AT+IPSCAN and what each one
does mean ?
Thank you for providing me a detailed description of the AT+IPSCAN command as well as its parameters.

Comment: https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/robocore-lojavirtual/709/HC-05_ATCommandSet.pdf